# Como puedo obtener los registros de un campo de una tabla, si primero tengo que comparar dos campos concatenados de dos tablas distintas?

Tags: mysql

Ejemplo de lo que quiero hacer pero no me devuelve ningun valor:

```
select select CONCAT('1','-22',valor,'-12')concatenado
from t1,t2 
where concatenado=registro
```

Bien mi base de datos maneja dos tablas proyectos y cuentas, donde proyectos tiene los campos partida, enero-diciembre y total mientras que cuentas tiene el campo cuenta, nombre_cuenta y deudor. Ahora bien lo que yo necesito es realizar una concatenacion con otros datos definidos mas la partida de la tabla proyectos, la cual debe ser similar al campo de cuenta de la tabla cuentas y asi poder compararlos y si son iguales entones debe arrojarme el campo deudor como resultado de dicha consulta.

Comment: de donde proviene valor? a que equivale? añade mas contexto por favor saludos y bienvenido

Comment: Mira [ask] <- ACA para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] <- ACA para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Answer (score 0):

deberias poner mas informacion... pero segun se entiende no se puede comparar datos dentro de una concatenacion, asu lugar en el where los especificas indicualmene.

```
select t1.deudor
from t1,t2 
where t1.cuenta= select CONCAT('1','-22',valor,'-12')concatenado
```

Pueba con esto, segun lo entendido deberia de ser asi, aunque lo veo algo poco funcional, en caso de que no arroje entonces se mas descriptivo y pon foros de las tablas y de los resultados que esperas...

By: JJ

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta, pero intenta no responder hasta que el usuario deje bien en claro cual es el problema.

Comment: Bien mi base de datos maneja dos tablas proyectos y cuentas, donde proyectos tiene los campos partida, enero-diciembre y total mientras que cuentas tiene el campo cuenta, nombre_cuenta y deudor. Ahora bien lo que yo necesito es realizar una concatenacion con otros datos definidos mas la partida de la tabla proyectos, la cual debe ser similar al campo de cuenta de la tabla cuentas y asi poder compararlos y si son iguales entones debe arrojarme el campo deudor como resultado de dicha consulta.

Comment: prueba con esta nueva que deje, esta si ha de servir...